# D3.js Barchart timescale : Uneven space between bars

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I guess the title explains the problem.  Similar questions on SO refer to ordinal scales.

x axis scale:

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { 
            return d.date; 
        }))
        .range([width/data.length/2, width-(width/data.length/2)]);
```

The bars

```
bars.enter()
    .append("rect")
        .classed("column", true)
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
        .attr("width", (width-(width/data.length)) / (data.length+2))
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date) - (width/data.length)/2; })
        .attr("y", height)
        .attr("height", 0)
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value);});
```

How can I amend this code so that I have a whole and equal number of pixels between each vertical bar, and thereby getting an even spacing ?

[image]

Comment: Use [`scale.rangeRound()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#rangeRound).

Comment: Can you please elaborate.  
I changed the scale to  .rangeRound([width/data.length/2, width-(width/data.length/2)]);
but still uneven, how should I edit the .attr('width', ...) ?

Comment: Ah, I missed that -- you need to use the scale to get the width of the bars as well (1 day?). It may be easier to use an ordinal scale that will give you the width of the bars directly.

Comment: So I can't divide the width of the scale by data.length and 1 to get a 1px space between bars ?

Comment: You're dividing the width of the page, not the width of the scale. This can (and in your case does) give you fractional pixel values. The `.rangeRound()` function avoids this for the scale, but then you have to use it to determine the width of the bars. As I've said, I'd use an ordinal scale in this case.